# Get CSV data from URL - Python

Tags: python, json, csv, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to export some csv data and I want to do it preferable by reading the data using the url and then exporting.

The url I want to get data from is: https://bank.gov.ua/en/markets/exchangerate-chart?startDate=2022-01-01&endDate=2022-07-11
and if you look at the bottom there is an option to download the data in csv format.

This is my code so far:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.content
```

If we call the data variable we get a byte type format of the webpage, and I just want to get the section of data illustrated in the picture which I guess has the heading of "data" followed by what seems a dictionary:

[image]

I am not really sure if there is a way of cleaning it all up or a way of indexing but I could really use some help.

Comment: It says Error 16 on the site.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are after starts after `window.exchangeRate = JSON.parse('`, and ends at `');`, so slice the response text (which is of type `str`) at those indexes, then use `json.loads` to transform the string to a dict.

```py
import requests
import json

url = r"https://bank.gov.ua/en/markets/exchangerate-chart?startDate=2022-01-01&endDate=2022-07-11"

response = requests.get(url)
text = response.text

left_str = r"window.exchangeRate = JSON.parse('"
right_str = r"');"

left = text.find(left_str) + len(left_str)
right = text.find(right_str, left)

data = json.loads(text[left:right])
```

See:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads